# How to compute $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} \left(\frac{1}{\ln (x^4) \sin (-\frac{1}{x})}\right)$?

Tags: limits

I have a problem with this limit, I don't know what method to use. I have no idea how to compute it.
Can you explain the method and the steps used?

$$\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} \left(\frac{1}{\ln (x^4) \sin (-\frac{1}{x})}\right)$$

Comment: what do you mean by $\sin x(- \frac{1}{x})$ ?

Comment: is it $\ln(x^4)$ or $(\ln(x))^4$?

Comment: i edited the limit

Comment: Did you try l'Hopital rule?

Comment: Did you try $x=\frac 1y$ ?

Comment: i don't know how to get 0/0 or inf/inf

Comment: the limit doesn' exist it is $-\infty$ by L'Hospital

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $$\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} \left(\frac{1}{\ln (x^4) \sin (-\frac{1}{x})}\right)$$

Hint: $$=\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} \left(\frac{1\bigg/\sin (-\frac{1}{x})}{\ln (x^4)}\right)$$ Now use L'hospital

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=\frac{1}{t}\implies t\to 0^+$ as $x\to +\infty$ $$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\ln(x^4)\sin\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)}\right)=\lim_{t\to 0^+}\left(\frac{1}{\ln\left(\frac 1t\right)^4\sin\left(-t\right)}\right)$$
$$=\lim_{t\to 0^+}\left(\frac{1}{4\ln(t)\sin\left(t\right)}\right)$$
$$=\frac 14\lim_{t\to 0^+}\left(\frac{t}{t\ln(t)\sin (t)}\right)$$
$$=\frac 14\lim_{t\to 0^+}\left(\frac{1}{t\ln(t)}\right)\cdot \lim_{t\to 0^+}\left(\frac{t}{\sin t}\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}(-\infty)(1)=\color{red}{-\infty}$$

Answer (score 0):

By L'Hopital's role we have,
$$
\frac{1}{4}\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\Big(\frac{1/(\ln(x))}{\sin(-1/x)}\Big)=\frac{1}{4}\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\Big(\frac{-x}{(\ln(x))^{2}\cos(-1/x)}\Big)=\frac{1}{4}\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\Big(\frac{-x}{(\ln(x))^{2}}\Big)=\\
\frac{1}{4}\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\Big(\frac{-1}{2(\ln(x))(1/x)}\Big)=\frac{1}{8}\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\Big(\frac{-x}{(\ln(x))^{2}}\Big)=\frac{1}{16}\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\Big(\frac{-1}{(\ln(x))(1/x)}\Big)=-\infty
$$

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $\sin t \sim_0 t$. Therefore
$$L = \lim_{x \to +\infty} -\frac{x}{4\ln x} = -\infty$$
since $\ln x = o(x)$.

Comment: This proof also works with $(\ln x)^4$.

Comment: @GEdgar Good point, since $\ln^\alpha x = o(x)$ still holds for $\alpha \in \mathbb R$.